# Converting Date data to proper DateTime Format before saving to DB?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping

I am regularly scraping and storing some dated data from a website into a rails app, but the dates given on the website are in the following format:

```
11/25/2012 01
```

Which is the date and hour.

I need to write some code to convert this into the default DateTime format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

but I'm new to Ruby.

Here is the code I have currently scraping the date-containing element with Nokogiri and extracting the text, maybe you could build off of this:

```
datedata = tr.css('td')[0].text
```

This scrapes the date table row and extracts the text.  E.g., `datedata = "11/25/2012 01"`

Is there a method that can convert `datedata` into default DateTime format for saving into a database?  FYI - Hours are the only time given, and they are necessary data for my use-case,  no minutes or seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DateTime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html)'s [`strptime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) function

```
[1] pry(main)> DateTime.strptime("11/25/2012 01", "%m/%d/%Y %H")
=> Sun, 25 Nov 2012 01:00:00 +0000
```

This should be enough to be passed to ActiveRecord, but if you want to convert this to the SQL  datetime string you mentioned in your question, you can use Rails [`to_formatted_s`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) with the `:db` option.

```
[2] pry(main)> DateTime.strptime("11/25/2012 01", "%m/%d/%Y %H").to_formatted_s(:db)
=> "2012-11-25 01:00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use chronic:

```
require 'chronic'
datedata = "11/25/2012 01"
Chronic.parse datedata
#=> 2012-11-25 13:00:00 0800
```

Hm, that 13:00 doesn't seem right, let's try:

```
Chronic.parse "#{datedata}:00"
#=> 2012-11-25 01:00:00 0800
```

That's better.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion.  Thanks for introducing me to Chronic.  I'm using it for this task as well as some others :)

Comment: yw, but if you use it, you should choose it.

Answer (score -1):

A little hint. When your users will enter date from various time zones, you will get a number of disgusting bugs with time. Common rule I use: store time in your database in UTC. It's simple: Time object has `.utc` method. User should have his time zone setting, so local offset for user can be easily calculated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Alex.  Fortunately, I'm organizing price data from a geographically fixed exchange.  So, I only have one time zone to deal with.  However, I will keep this in mind for my next project.  Take care!